# Looping to subfolder batch file repeats same folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

Idea was to merge all jpg files in separate folders in the directory of the batch files to a new folder without any subdirectories. It worked as expected for a few hours but now it keeps looping copying the same files of the first folder again and again. Any clue on what is really wrong?

```
@echo off
::rmdir /S .\merge
::pause
mkdir .\merge
call :treeProcess
goto :eof
::pause
:treeProcess
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
echo %%f
xcopy .\*.jpg ..\merge\  /Y
)
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
exit /b
```

Comment: If you're calling a label whilst you're still in that label, how do you exit it? Also your script may be `xcopy`ing to several different destination directories! First of all you're creating a `merge` directory in the current directory, _(the directory of the batch file may not necessarily be the same)_. Then you `xcopy` files in the current directory matching `*.jpg` to a directory named `merge` one level above it, `..\merge`. When you step into each of your next level subdirectories, regardless of the overall depth, each time your files are being copied to a directory one level above that.

Comment: After cppying files the control is going back to the directory for loop and again goes to the other directory by treeprocess. Funny think is I copied more than 10000 files like that and then it stopped working in another folder. I thought rmdir(commented) & mkdir .\merge before starting treeprocess is affecting the control and removed both. Later I used xcopy .\%%f as shown below(as answer) to avoid copying all files inside single folder multiplied by total number of files before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution but still confused as if I remove `echo %%G`, `echo %%H`, `echo back to` .. the code still fails saying `( unexpected at this time`.

```
@echo off
::SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
::rmdir /S .\merge
::pause
::mkdir .\merge
dir /b /a-d
cd .
call :treeProcess
goto :eof
pause
:treeProcess
REM rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
for %%G in (*.jpg) do (
    echo %%G
    echo %%H
    ::echo inside %%H
    REM rem xcopy .\*.jpg ..\merge\ /e /Y
    xcopy .\%%G ..\merge\  /Y
)
FOR /D %%H in (*20*) do (
    cd %%H
    rem dir /b /a-d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
    echo back to ..
)
REM exit /b
REM :treeProcess
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
REM %%G is a good choice because it does not conflict with any of the pathname format letters (a, d, f, n, p, s, t, x) and provides the longest run of non-conflicting letters for use as implicit parameters.
REM G > H > I > J > K > L > M
REM Format letters are case sensitive, so using a capital letter is also a good way to avoid conflicts %%A rather than %%a.
exit /b
```

Comment: don't use `::`. Inside a command block. That results in unexpected behavior. (better: don't use it at all. It's a malformed label. The proper command for a comment/remark is `REM`)